# Why is the emitter resistance not reflected to base?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, resistance

Considering the first circuit, I want to determine the output resistance seen looking into collector of Q17. When the source \$v_i\$ is zeroed out as shown in the second figure, shouldn't the resistance across the transistor Q16 be considered \$r_{\pi16}\$ instead of \$r_{e16}\$?Because \$r_{e16}\$ isn't directly connected to ground. It is reflected to the base and that base resistance is connected to ground.

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"resistance across the transistor Q16 "_ I guess you mean looking into Q16 Emitter, right? Anyway, I find the 2nd schematic to be correct _if_ you neglect \$r_{o16}\$. Can you clarify your question? \$r_{\pi}\$ is found when looking into BJT _base_.

Comment: Thanks I got an epiphany while writing to clarify. I was basically confused of how \$r_{o16}\$  can be connected to ground. I realized that since base is grounded the connection to ground is obvious. @edmz